# A PHP function that adds # hashtag to an array of words

Tags: php, function, foreach, hashtag

I'm trying to write a function that adds the sign # to an array of words in a string

Given I can use the str_replace for each one of them but my array is getting bigger and it's not efficient.

```php
$needles = array('a', 'c', 'd');
$haystack = 'a b c d e f g';
    foreach($needles as $what) {
        if(strpos($haystack, $what)!==false) {
     $haystack = str_replace($needles, '#'.$what.'-', $haystack);
    }
    }
echo $haystack;
```

The array here is needles **a c d** in a haystack of  **a b c d e f g**
I'm trying to make them #a #b #c so that the result would be  **#a b #c #d e f g**

Comment: How big is your array going to get?

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong this str_replace() function
Read more about this function here [str_replace function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$needles = array('a', 'c', 'd');
$haystack = 'a b c d e f g';

    foreach($needles as $key) {
        if(strpos($haystack, $key)!==false) {
     $haystack = str_replace($key, '#'.$key, $haystack);
    }
    }
echo $haystack;
```

Output

```
#a b #c #d e f g
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is any faster you would have to benchmark it, but this solution works. Regex is slow, but iterating through a string once should be faster than looking through it N times.

```
<?php
$needles = array('a', 'c', 'd');
$haystack = 'a b c d e f g';
$reg = '~(['.implode($needles).'])~';

echo preg_replace ( $reg, '#$1' , $haystack );
```

Output

```
#a b #c #d e f g
```

Answer (score 0):

How can it be optimized:

1. Limit amount instructions that needs to be executed for each needle
2. Use such instructions that are faster
3. Change execution path approach so whole app uses solution in more efficient way

so it goes:

1. strpos($haystack, $what) - this function can be removed
2. str_replace() can be replaced with in_array() that should be faster.
3. In your example code str_replace() needs to search for a letter to change whole $haystack length multiplied by count of needles so if haystack is 10 characters long and you have 5 needles this means that str_replace does search on total 500 characters (5 times search in 100 char string). If there are not 5 but 10 needles and haystack is 1000 chars then the length jumps up to 10k length in total characters for str_replace to process. That's why you see a dramatic slow down of execution when you increase number of needles or/and haystack length. Ideally the search should be done once for whole haystack length so if there are 5 needles and haystack is 100 chars the search should be done only once and at the total characters of 100 chars that the search need to look at.
   Additionally: For long strings that are stored in files you may skip loading them into memory at all by using streams and read them one by one character directly from the file and replacing them on the fly.

code:

```
<?php

$needles = array('a', 'c', 'd');
$haystack = 'a b c d e f g';

function convert($needles, $haystack) {

    if(is_resource($haystack)) {
        $stream = $haystack;
    } else {
        $stream = fopen('data://text/plain,' . $haystack,'r');
    }

    while($char = fgetc($stream)) {
        if(in_array($char, $needles)) {
            $result = '#' . $char;
        } else {
            $result = $char;
        }

        yield $result;
    }

    if(is_resource($stream)) {
        fclose($stream);
    }
}

# use with haystack as string
$converted = convert($needles, $haystack);

# or use when haystack is in file
// $filePath = 'test-file.txt';
// $fileResource = fopen($filePath, 'r');
// $converted = convert($needles, $fileResource);

//echo converted string char by char
foreach($converted as $convertedChar) {
    echo $convertedChar;
}
```

gives:

```
#a b #c #d e f g
```

how to use:

put `function convert() {}` definition wherever you like and later use it:

```
$needles = array('a', 'c', 'd');
$haystack = 'a b c d e f g';

$converted = convert($needles, $haystack);
```

`$converted` is now a kind of array that each element of it is one character of the string that is converted. So to get all characters echoed you treat it as an array

`['#a', 'b', '#c', '#d', 'e', 'f', 'g']`

and echo inside foreach loop:

```
//echo converted string char by char
foreach($converted as $convertedChar) {
    echo $convertedChar;
}
```

the nice thing is that the "kind of array" is never created it only looks and feels like an array for `foreach` but actually it returns only one character modified foreach iteration. Therefore a memory consumption of convert() is almost nothing.

the second approach (ad 3.) is to read whole haystack from file and process it on the fly. This approach can handle even very large haystack because it does not read it to the memory at once and store whole before processing but reads one char from input and then change it and echoes, and another one.

comment this block of code:

```
//$converted = convert($needles, $haystack);
```

and uncomment this:

```
# or use when haystack is in file
$filePath = 'test-file.txt';
$fileResource = fopen($filePath, 'r');
$converted = convert($needles, $fileResource);
```

then echo like before with foreach

```
//echo converted string char by char
foreach($converted as $convertedChar) {
    echo $convertedChar;
}
```

if you want to store converted text into string you can do it like that:

```
    $convertedStr = '';
    foreach($converted as $convertedChar) {
        $convertedStr .= $convertedChar;
    }

    //and echo or save later
    echo $convertedStr;
```